# Encrypting an email using IronPort in .Net

Tags: email, encryption, cisco

My organization uses Cisco Ironport to enable users to send encrypted outgoing emails. The users use an outlook plugin to get the email encrypted.

One of my applications sends emails to our clients. I want to be able to use IronPort to encrypt these outgoing emails from my application.

Question

1. Does IronPort have an API or something which I can use to achieve this? My application is written in .Net.
2. If not any alternatives I may have.

Thanks
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

To allow the encryption of smtp sourced email by an Ironport you need to setup a content filter on the Ironport that would invoke an encryption profile. Your application would place a content filter keyword in your message in order to get it encrypted. Requires coordination with your Ironport administrator.

Since this post is a bit old please mark as correct for others if appropriate.